# How to specify in which pages stripejs script can be loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, next.js

Stripe's script is causing a lot of main-thread blocking as is shown in the image from
Google Insights

[image: Google Insights Image]

My issue with this is that the page that is being affected is just a page with no need for stripe.
but apparently stripejs library inserts its third party script in the head of the page, so this being a SPA, it means it is in every page.

How do I make that this third party script is only inserted in components that actively use the library ?

Other ways to just improve or ease the blocking would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: You can wrap the component using stripe with `next/dynamic`.

Comment: @brc-dd thanks, I ended up moving all stripe logic to a component a made it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You could use script tag with `async` inside `next/head` component on the needed page:

```
import Head from 'next/head';

// ...

        <Head>
          <script async src="https://js.stripe.com/v3" />
        </Head>
```

It would only be downloaded if user requests that page.

Although [Stripe recommends](https://stripe.com/docs/js/including) to use it on every page:

> To best leverage Stripe’s advanced fraud functionality, include this script on every page, not just the checkout page.